# Issues getting table headers to position correctly

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, html-table

I am having difficulties with a table I am trying to create.

I have a users array that displays the users in my database table. There is 10 users in this. Then I should have 14 players under each user. Like this...

user1        user2      user3

player1      player1    player1

player2     player2     player2

player3     player3     player3

etc..

Right now it is doing this

[image]

Here is my code...

```
<table class="draft_border_table">
        <tr>
            <th>Rnd</th>
            <th><?php echo "<div>" . $draft_order_row['username'] . "</div>"; ?></th>
<?php               
while($draft_order_row = mysqli_fetch_array($draft_order_stmt)) {
?>  

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player1 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player2 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player3 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player4 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player5 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player6 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player7 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player8 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player9 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player10 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player11 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player12 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player13 . "</div>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player14 . "</div>"; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>        
<?php
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
<table class="draft_border_table">
        <tr>
            <th>Rnd</th>

<?php 
while($draft_username_row = mysqli_fetch_array($draft_order_stmt2)) {
    $username = $draft_username_row['username'];
?>

                <th><?php echo "<div>" . $username . "</div>"; ?></th>
<?php
}
?>
            </tr>
<?php
$count = 1;
while($draft_order_row = mysqli_fetch_array($draft_order_stmt)) {
    $count + 1;
    $player1 = $draft_order_row['player1'];
    $player2 = $draft_order_row['player2'];
    $player3 = $draft_order_row['player3'];
    $player4 = $draft_order_row['player4'];
    $player5 = $draft_order_row['player5'];
    $player6 = $draft_order_row['player6'];
    $player7 = $draft_order_row['player7'];
    $player8 = $draft_order_row['player8'];
    $player9 = $draft_order_row['player9'];
    $player10 = $draft_order_row['player10'];
    $player11 = $draft_order_row['player11'];
    $player12 = $draft_order_row['player12'];
    $player13 = $draft_order_row['player13'];
    $player14 = $draft_order_row['player14'];
?>
<tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player1 . "</div>"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player2 . "</div>"; ?></td>
            </tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table class="draft_border_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Rnd</th>
<?php

while ($draft_user_row = mysqli_fetch_array($draft_order_stmt2)) {

    $username = $draft_user_row['username'];

    echo "<th><div>" . $username . "</div></th>";

}
?>

    </tr>

<?php
for ($count = 1; $count < 15; $count++) {

    $col = "player" . $count;
    $query = "SELECT $col FROM user_players ORDER BY id";
    $draft_order_stmt = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    echo "<tr><td>" . $count . "</td>";

    while (list($players) = mysqli_fetch_array($draft_order_stmt)) {

        echo "<td><div class=\"draftBorder\">";

        if ($players == NULL) {

            $players = "&nbsp;";

        }

        echo $players . "</div></td>";

    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: It is kind of doing it, but it puts the users info instead of the players.

Comment: Then we need to turn your player list into an array, give me a minute or two to edit my answer.

Comment: If you look at my updated question. I made some changes to my code and you can see the users are posting inline, but now the inputs aren't in blocks under them.

Comment: Because you are starting a new row with each player.

Comment: It is almost there. It is making columns for items in my database, rather than making rows for the players. There should be 14 rows for players and then only columns for my users.

Comment: If I change my code from what I was trying and only have the players in one `<tr>` I get what exactly what your code is doing except the count still doesn't work. So, it looks like your code is giving all the rows for the players, but instead of having them appear vertically up and down for each user they are displaying horizontally for as many users as there are,

Comment: I am trying to get it to look something like this, but the usernames where it says 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. http://lockerroomfantasysports.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/FantasySports-Fantasy-Football-Draft-Board.jpg

Comment: Do you have any issues with putting the users down the left column and putting the round numbers at the top?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88907/discussion-between-paul-and-angelo-demichaels).

Comment: No, I can't do that. It would mess the whole thing up.

Comment: @Paul This should do it now.